# Time to the nearest 15 min interval

Tags: powershell

This is the code I am using to round the Date to 15-minute interval (00,15,30,45)

as you can see from the example it only rounds down

How can I fix this so it rounds to The actual nearest 15 minutes instead of just rounding it down?

```
try
{$TodayDate = Get-Date -Date "6/25/2019 12:46:22"}
catch
{$TodayDate = Get-Date -Date "25/06/2019 12:46:22"}

$Date1 = $TodayDate
$Date2 = $TodayDate.AddMinutes(-2)
Write-Host "Actual Date: $Date1"
Write-Host "Rounded Date: $($Date1.AddMinutes(- $Date1.Minute % 15 ))"
Write-Host "Actual Date: $Date2"
Write-Host "Rounded Date: $($Date2.AddMinutes(- $Date2.Minute % 15 ))"
```

Actual Date: 06/25/2019 12:46:22

Rounded Date: 06/25/2019 12:45:22

Actual Date: 06/25/2019 12:44:22

Rounded Date: 06/25/2019 12:30:22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you crosspost the same question at the same time to different forums you should at least post links to the other forums along with your question to avoid people willing to help you making their work twice or more.

Thanks

https://forums.powershell.org/t/time-to-the-nearest-15-min-interval/17238?u=olaf

Here is my code suggestion for getting the current date/time *rounded* to the nearest 15 minutes:

```
$FifteenMinutes = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15 ).Ticks
$Date = Get-Date
$Ticks = ([Math]::Round($Date.Ticks / $FifteenMinutes, 0) * $FifteenMinutes) -as [long]
[DateTime]$Ticks
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$9e9 = (Get-Date 0).AddMinutes(15).Ticks # 9,000,000,000
$TodayDate = Get-Date -Date "6/25/2019 12:46:22"
$Date1 = $TodayDate
$Date2 = $TodayDate.AddMinutes(-2)
Write-Host "Actual Date: $Date1"
Write-Host "Rounded Date: $(Get-Date ($9e9 * ([int]($Date1.Ticks / $9e9))))"
Write-Host "Actual Date: $Date2"
Write-Host "Rounded Date: $(Get-Date ($9e9 * ([int]($Date2.Ticks / $9e9))))"
```

Yields:

```
Actual Date: 06/25/2019 12:46:22
Rounded Date: 06/25/2019 12:45:00
Actual Date: 06/25/2019 12:44:22
Rounded Date: 06/25/2019 12:45:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try { $TodayDate = Get-Date -Date '6/25/2019 12:46:22' }
catch { $TodayDate = Get-Date -Date '25/06/2019 12:46:22' }

$Date1 = $TodayDate
Write-Host "Actual Date: $Date1"
Write-Host "Rounded Date: $( $Date1.AddMinutes( $Date1.Minute % 15 -le 7 ? -($Date1.Minute % 15) : 15 - ($Date1.Minute % 15)) )"

$Date2 = $TodayDate.AddMinutes(-2)
Write-Host "Actual Date: $Date2"
Write-Host "Rounded Date: $( $Date2.AddMinutes( $Date2.Minute % 15 -le 7 ? -($Date2.Minute % 15) : 15 - ($Date2.Minute % 15)) )"
```

Result

```
Actual Date: 06/25/2019 12:46:22
Rounded Date: 06/25/2019 12:45:22
Actual Date: 06/25/2019 12:44:22
Rounded Date: 06/25/2019 12:45:22
```